# How to pass PHP array to Postgres query as a parameter

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I try to pass a PHP array to Postgres as below but I'm getting an error;

```
$arrayIDs = array('24','7','8','9','13');

$data = SelectItemsForUpdate($arrayIDs);

function SelectItemsForUpdate($arrayIDs) 
{ 
  $query = PrepareQuery('select id, quantity from items where id in ($1) for update ');      
  $result = ExecutePreparedQuery($query, Array($arrayIDs));          
  ...
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postgres arrays expect curly braces, while PHP emplys round braces. So first implode the aray as below and then pass it as parameter using ANY operator.

The following syntax works:

```
$arrayIDs = '{'.implode(', ',$arrayIDs).'}';               
$query = PrepareQuery('select id, quantity from items where id = ANY($1)');
$result = ExecutePreparedQuery($query, Array($arrayIDs));
```

Comment: Finally found a life saver, thank you!